# Tell the difference between root page and not found

Tags: next.js

In my root layout.tsx, I have the following code:

```
const path = headers().get("next-url");
let top_margin = "mt-[70px]",
    content_padding = "p-2 pt-3";
if (!path || path === "/") {
    top_margin = "mt-[120px]";
    content_padding = "";
}
```

The idea being that on my landing page, I have my header bigger, and thus want the top margin different. However, when I hit a not found page, the path shows up as null, which makes sense I guess. I'm not sure how to check if I'm at my actual root or at the not found or other similar situations that may arise.

Comment: Maybe this could be of use https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48710#discussioncomment-5777561

Comment: I think you could add a separate component for your 404 page and add the customization there instead of your layout https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-error

Comment: @Trevor usePathname returns null or `/` even when I go to a path that doesn't exist.

@DanielCruz I do have a separate 404 component, but it's the other way around, I want just the root to have different styling. Maybe it means I need to restructure my page, but I'm not sure how.